# Customize date format in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, date, format

I have this function:

```
void Log::Write(string logline){
//2011-10-12 13:07:40 correct format
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    m_stream.write( asctime (timeinfo), 24 );
    m_stream << " - " << logline << std::endl;
}
```

The output is like this:

> Thu Oct 13 12:35:30 2011

but I wanna see the output like the comment section:

> 2011-10-12 13:07:40

How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very possible. Look at the manpage for `strftime()`. In this case, you'd want:

```
void Log::Write(string line) 
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    strftime (buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
    m_stream << buffer << " - " << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok ty.
I dunno why, but I got in the log file strange asci chars like this:
2011-10-13 17:27:13 ·öÚp·ô¯u·83T 3T§¿§¿ô¯u·ïª
How can I avoid this?

Comment: don't use m_stream.write; it's always putting 80 characters down. instead, just use the stream operator. Changed to fix.

Comment: Ok no problem! I've solved with:
m_stream.write(buffer, 19);
because there are always 19 chars :)
Ty!

Comment: It works, but if you change the format it'll break. The `<<` operator relies on `strlen()` so it'll always write the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Boost offers a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`strftime()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strftime.3.html) function to format times in all ways you want. In your case the format string `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` should produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strftime() to convert a struct tm into a string with somewhat flexible formatting.