# Library to discover dates from text?

Tags: c++, parsing, date, nlp, string-parsing

I need to pull a date out of a string. Since not everyone uses the [official ISO format](http://xkcd.com/1179/) when printing their dates, it is impractical to write a date parser for every possible date format that could be used, and I need to handle as many date formats as possible - I don't control the data and can't expect it to come in a specific format.

This seems like a problem that has probably already been solved ages ago, but my Google-fu is too weak to find the solution. :(

Does there already exist a C++ library that, given a string, will return the month, day, year, hour, minute, second, etc that is referenced in that string, if any?

Pseudocode:

```
string s1 = "There is an expected meteor shower this Thursday,"
            "August 15th 2013 at 4:39 AM.";
string s2 = "20130815T04:39:00";
date d1 = magicConverter(s1);
date d2 = magicConverter(s2);
assert(d1 == d2);
```

Comment: The Javascript Date parser is pretty robust... you might take a look at what they're doing in some of the more popular engines

Answer (score -1):

You might use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753145/customize-date-format-in-c), but you need to configure a mask, that tells the code which time format is used. If you write a class routine, that takes a mask and a string and gets you out the time and is able to print in any format you like, you should be well prepared. You have to look in more detail, if it also supports Daynames and Monthnames. I got it to work in python with a module providing a function that seems pretty much the same.

For more detail:

Please look at the example 2013-08-03 again. Nobody and as follows no computer is able to tell you if this date belongs to August or April, except of having a mask telling JJJJ-MM-DD or JJJJ-DD-MM. Also this library may tell you only standard masked times. So it might lead you to August in this case. But as you said it can be any date declaration, thus it does not need to follow standards, thus it can also mean March. An other possibility is to tell you about the date from the context (e.g. a table with a column of all te same time formats by looking for the increase (which would also fail if you just look at one day per month for just one year).

Another example... if I ask you 2013-05-04... to which month does it belong? You might tell me... April. I would reply "no, to the 4th of May" and vice versa for May and 5th of April. If you tell me how to solve this puzzle with two possible solutions I would understand your downvote... please think before downvoting someone trying to help you.

Comment: This won't work. As I mentioned in the question, I specifically don't know and can't control the format of the date.

Comment: But if you dont know the format of the date, how shall your code know it. The code only sees characters. It is not even able to distinguish 2013-08-03 if it does not now if 08 or 03 is the day. I think without knowing the exact format it is impossible. But you would get close enough with my suggestion...

Comment: Actually there exists Java libraries like the [Stanford NLP libraries](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml) that do exactly this. Unfortunately, integrating a Java library into my C++ application is not an option I'm willing to go forward with at this moment. I'm looking for something similar to Stanford's `SUTime` in C++.

Comment: @CoryKlein: There is no need to integrate the Java code in C++. I often need to make tools work together. When in a situation similar to yours, I'd create a service around `SUTime`, that accepts raw sentences over a socket, to send back tagged sentences.